# How do I disable and remove Upsource integration from YouTrack

Tags: youtrack, upsource

Having tried Upsource we don't have a compelling need for it at the moment, so I've removed it from our integration server to reduce the load.

Upsource has been removed as a service from Hub.

In YouTrack, if I go to Administration...Upsource Integration Settings, I still have a link between YouTrack and Upsource. I can disable it, but I can't see any UI that lets me delete the link between my YouTrack project and Upsource project.

On the VCS changes tab in YouTrack it then complains about Upsource integration being disabled.

How can I remove the Upsource link from YouTrack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible to disable Upsource integration at the moment, not remove it. Here's the corresponding feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-35295